# Getting live video on an android app from a wireless camera

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

I am trying to make a system wherein I need to send live video covered on an external wireless camera (not phone camera) to an android app I am going to make. The camera's I searched for only send videos to their own apps. So, is it possible in some way to design an app which will be able to take that live video? The camera is connected to the phone through Wifi. I need to process the video for some real time application, so I will need the live video only and not after it gets saved through their app. I have no prior experience in android, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are trying to run before learning to crawl. I suggest you start with a simpler task as a first application.

Comment: Yes, I know. But my actual aim here is to get the video and use it for further processing for object detection. But, I cant seem to find a way around this. Is there any other way of doing this without getting too much into android?